# Scala: Function0 vs by-name parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Can anyone give a definitive answer on how by-name parameters `=> T` and `Function0` parameters `() => T` are transformed into one another by the Scala compiler? I know they are not the same, but the difference is very subtle as they can be interchangeably used in many scenarios.

Example: if I define

```
def someFunction: Int = 2
def f(x: => Int): Unit = println(x)
```

then I can successfully call

```
f(2)
f(someFunction)
```

How is `() => Int` an acceptable replacement for `=> Int`?

**More generally, is `() => T` a universally acceptable replacement for a by-name `=> T` parameter?**

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong on the following reasoning: `=> T` is never an acceptable replacement for `() => T` because the first is a value type (`T`), the other is a function type. That is, if I have `def f(x: () => Int)`, I'll never be able to pass an `Int`, or a lazy `Int` (doesn't even make sense anyway as there are no lazy types).

Comment: Your examples are definitely *not* equivalent. The first one produces a `Try[() ⇒ Int]`, the second one a `Try[Int]`. Your function argument of type `() ⇒ Int` gets converted to `⇒ T` with `T` being `() ⇒ Int`.

Comment: Some good info here: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html

Comment: They do not replace each other and they are not transformed into one another by the Scala compiler. They are simply different things and usually serve different purposes.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet point definitely taken, you're right. Changed my example to accommodate.

Comment: In you updated example, `someFunction` is _not_ a function. If it _were_ a function then `f(someFunction)` would not compile.

Comment: If I `def someFunction(): Int = 2` the code still compiles with the note that the compiler actually interprets `f(someFunction)` as `f(someFunction())`.

Comment: But `def someFunction(): Int = 2` is not a function.  It is a method. Methods can be turned into functions but they are not the same thing. Try this `val realFunc = someFunction _` then you'll have a real function and you'll see that `f(realFunc)` won't compile.

Comment: @webuster Hi, is this resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, here's the full breakdown.

```
def value: Int = ???
def method(): Int = ???

def f1(f: () => Int) = ???
def f2(f: => Int) = ???

f1(value)  // fails
f1(method) // works
f2(value)  // works
f2(method) // works with a warning "empty-paren method accessed as parameterless"
```

1. > f1(value)

This one fails because `f1` is expecting a Unit => Int function, but is given an Int value.

2. > f1(method)

This one works because `f1` is expecting a function, and is given a method. Here's the difference: method is not a value in Scala; it cannot exist on its own and is an attribute of the context it's defined in (class, trait, object etc.). Function is a value; it can be kept in a collection, taken as argument in another function, returned from a function etc. When the compiler is expecting a function and is given a method, it performs *eta expansion*. Given a function e.g. `f: (a: Int, b: Int) => Int`, eta expansion is a process of creation of another layer around that while preserving the signature, so it becomes `(a: Int, b: Int) => f(a, b)`. This technique is useful because we can turn methods into function. Given some method `def f(a: Int): Int = ???`, we can perform eta-expansion to create a function of type Int => Int out of it: `(a: Int) => f(a)`. I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/on-method-invocations-or-what-exactly-is-eta-expansion-1019b37e010c) about this some time ago if you're interested.

3. > f2(value)

Works without surprises, but pay attention to the fact that the passed value is accessed every time it's used in the function body.

4. > f2(method)

Works, but with a warning that we are invoking a method that is defined with empty parenthesis by using no parenthesis. Good practice is to use methods without parenthesis (e.g. `f`) when they simply represent a value, but one that is recalculated every time it's accessed, e.g. `numberOfUpvotes`, and to use methods with empty parenthesis (e.g. `f()`) when some kind of side-effect is performed and hence the method isn't idempotent, e.g. `createSnapshot()` (again, this should not be present in purely functional code).

Word of advice: don't encumber your mind with what's a replacement for what. Don't use replacements. If something needs a function, provide it a function. If it needs a value, provide a value. If a method is defined without parens, invoke it without parens. If it has parens, invoke it with parens.

If you need to go from method to function and compiler is expecting a function, eta-expansion will happen automatically. If it's not expecting a function, you need to do it manually.

```
def f(): Int = ???
val a = f               // no function context; a is a string
val b: () => Int = f    // b is a function Unit => Int
val c = f2 _            // c is a function Unit => Int
```

Last case is a partially applied function. I feel like I'm going too broad now so I will stop here. I hope this helped.